# Class not creating new instances upon repeated calls

Tags: python, class, oop, heap-memory

May be I am missing something really basic here, but when I define a class in the following manner:

```
class Arbitrary(object):
    """Arbitary class to test init"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = dict()
```

and repeatedly instantiate the class in the following way

```
for i in range(5):
    a = Arbitrary()
    print '{}  {}  {}  {}'.format(i, a, id(a), a.x)
```

I am not getting totally new instances of `Arbitrary()` class as I expect it to. In fact, I am getting repetition of two instances:

```
0  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x1006cb110>  4302090512  {}
1  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x1006cb190>  4302090640  {}
2  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x1006cb110>  4302090512  {}
3  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x1006cb190>  4302090640  {}
4  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x1006cb110>  4302090512  {}
```

Why is that?

How can I define the `__init__` in my class such that every new call to `Arbitrary()` would return a totally new instance?

Comment: Those objects are having the only references to them removed by the next iteration. So why wouldn't the interpreter reuse the memory?

Comment: This was an extreme example to illustrate the problem. My experience has been that two separate calls to Arbitrary() returned the same instance, which voids the purpose. Trying to figure out why that is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Instead make a list of `Arbitrary` objects and see if it still happens.

Comment: @PradeepReddyRaamana: "My experience has been that two separate calls to Arbitrary() returned the same instance". With the given class definition, no that didn't happen. You are mistaken. Keep a reference to the older instances, and you'll find that the `id`s do not repeat so long as the older instances are not discarded. You could also confirm this by doing something silly between iterations, e.g. `a.x[i] = i` and confirming that the values are not sticking around on future iterations, even with the `id` is the same.

Comment: I checked that. There it is not happening. Something odd about this type of instantiation, or perhaps I am missing something really basic.

Comment: @PradeepReddyRaamana: It's not odd. It's that when you replace `a` with a new instance, the old instance's memory is returned to the heap for reuse. `id` is only guaranteed to be unique at a given point in time, not for the life of the program; when the first instance is released (almost immediately after the second instance is created), its memory is available for reuse (in this case, the third instance reuses that memory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Python expert but I can see you are overwring your instances. I tried changing it to below and it runs ok :

```
#!/bin/env python

class Arbitrary(object):
    """Arbitary class to test init"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = dict()

a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append(Arbitrary())
    print '{}  {}  {}  {}'.format(i, a[i], id(a[i]), a[i].x)
```

result :

```
ckim@stph45:~/python/test2] test2.py
0  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x7fc6952b6090>  140490882900112  {}
1  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x7fc6952b6250>  140490882900560  {}
2  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x7fc6952b6290>  140490882900624  {}
3  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x7fc6952b62d0>  140490882900688  {}
4  <__main__.Arbitrary object at 0x7fc6952b6310>  140490882900752  {}
```

Comment: You're correct. Python does automatic garbage collection and in the OP's code the previous value of `a` was discarded each time a new value was assigned to it. Not sure why it's apparently keeping at least two of them around—probably just in case more than one is ever needed..

Comment: The second object just happens to be created before the first one is garbage collected. In this case the order doesn't matter, but it would if you had a statement like `a = a + ['some', 'list'].